# ¿como arreglar el error Could not scan for classes inside "...." which does not appear to be a file nor a folder en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer

estoy tratando de añadir una librería a mi proyecto de laravel, pero no puedo usar composer así que la añadí en el composer.json en el autoload y trato de correr el comando composer dump-autoload pero aparece este error  `Could not scan for classes inside "libraries/ApiRedsysIS" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder`
no estoy seguro de porque, todos los archivos dentro de la librería son archivos php hay mas carpetas dentro pero no son muchas

```
  "classmap": [
        "libraries/ApiRedsysIS"
    ],
```

¿porque sucede este error? si me pueden guiar a la respuesta o darme alguna sugerencia lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: por qué no puedes usar composer? cómo instalaste las dependencias de laravel sin composer?

Comment: es una librería para una pasarela de pagos, pero no tiene repositorio, solo es el .zip que estaba en su pagina web, por eso no puedo usar composer tuve que usar otro método, no mas que no me esta funcionando.